# Zend Framework output ready prepared statement

Tags: sql, zend-framework

How to output sql statement right before it's launched?

To check all placed data inside prepared statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend_Db doesn't have a mechanism itself to output the sql statements that it generates. What you can do is modify the public method "query" in Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(line 445 in 1.10.6) to output the $sql local variable. The query method is called by both the update and insert methods.

Comment: Look at Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug - attach it to your Db adapter and it will output your queries, the time they take, plus the data that gets injected into them.  The Zend Framework manual's usage is fairly straight forward for this.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a way to output the SQL it generates

```
$select = $db->select()->from('elements')
                       ->where('id = ?', $this->_Id);
$sql = $select->__toString();
echo $sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

echo (string) $select;